# Creating a number from digits stored in array using C

Tags: c, arrays, digits

Now I have this number 193456787 stored in an array in C with each digit in a cell, how do I construct a four digit number from the digits in even numbered positions for example like 9468 ?

Comment: With some thinking and some code?

Answer (score 0):

Well, quite obviously:

```
const int digits[] = { 1, 9, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 7 };
const int num = 1000 * digits[1] + 100 * digits[3] + 10 * digits[5] + digits[7];
```

Just add the digits together, scaled by the appropriate weights of course.

Comment: Isn't there a `10 *` missing before `digits[5]` ?